# semantic-release-monorepo ignores pkgRoot

Tags: node.js, git, github, semantic-release

I created a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/eng-dibo/tmp-semantic-release) which is a monorepo contains only one workspace in `./package' dir

both root and package (the workspace) have exactly the same release.config.js file except that package extends `semantic-release-monorepo`.

both of them use the default configurations and only two plugins

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    ["@semantic-release/npm", { pkgRoot: "dist" }],
  ],
  // extends: ["semantic-release-monorepo"],
};
```

the important part here is that `@semantic-release/npm` uses `{ pkgRoot: "dist" }`

`package` contents are typically the same as the root including `dist` folder, except the package name.

if I run `semantic-release` from the root, i.e without `semantic-release-monorepo` it packs the package as expected, and puts the contents of `pkgRoot` dir in the top-level of the published package.

in contrast, when I run the same command from `package`, i.e with `semantic-release-monorepo`, it ignores the option `pkgRoot` and the packed packages contain the folder `dist` instead of its contents.

**steps for reproduction**
1- clone [the repo](https://github.com/eng-dibo/tmp-semantic-release) and install dependencies
2- remove all local and remote tags if exist
3- switch to the branch `next`
4- modify root's and package's files and create feat/fix commits
5- run the script `release` from the root and package and see the tarball's contents in both cases

you will see different behavior.